# store/select monetory values (credit/debit) mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am storing monetary values in mysql database. a credit is stored as say `20.00` while a debit is stored as -5.00. and then whew i need the current balance i so a

```
Select Sum(amount)
```

which in this case give me `15.00`

**example table 1**

```
uid  amt
1    20
1    -5
```

**example table 2**

```
uid  amt type
1    20   crd
1    5    dbt
```

Then in the case of a history of accounts, i can just

```
select * from amount
```

Because this is monitory values, and since database systems like mysql depreciates features every now and then i am afraid if this is the right way to do things, i also thought of adding another field which may indicate the type of transaction like

```
crd for credit
dbt for debit
etc
```

what would be your suggestions/the best way to do this?

Comment: Store it as a decimal or float.

Comment: Exactly what features are you afraid of being deprecated?

Comment: i rather choose to store it as `20 and -5` than adding extra column which determines whether it is credit or debit.

Comment: @MarkBaker currently, i don't know yet, of course no one know which features might be deprecated next. i just need something that is `deprecation resistant`

Comment: @DanBracuk as in the first example `20, -5, etc`

Comment: @Smith you think that MySQL is going to deprecate negative numbers?

Comment: You're not using any special features that are likely to go away. Are you worried they might deprecate negative numbers?

Comment: @Barmar not necessarily, but  need to be sure if this is right. its my first time doing monetary application

Comment: @Smith - I think you're worrying excessively about deprecation of "features".... you're not using any special features that might be likely to be deprecated, only basic SQl

Comment: To be more specific, you should really not be concerned that they might remove anything that's part of ANSI SQL. Implementation-dependent features like `IFNULL` might (but probably won't) go away, but `COALESCE` won't. And just basic arithmetic like negative numbers are so fundamental to all computing that you really don't have to worry.

Comment: the seperate credit/debit values is kind of redundant, when you could just use the signedness of the value to indicate that.

Comment: @DanBracuk NEVER EVER EVER store money as a float!!!  When you don't have access to a decimal data type, just store it as cents with an int.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would make a lot more sense to me to store the data as it is (i.e. be explicit) and use a negative number.  Should you use an unsigned decimal and store the type, you can still do it though.

```
SELECT SUM(IF(type = 'dbt', -1 * amount, amount))
```

Comment: how would i get a balance in this case

Comment: You would use a case construct.  But you are asking for details of worse of the two options.

Comment: I did Select SUM(amount) from exampleTable group by type, and it would return 2 rows the first one is for debit and the other one for credit.. then I had to calculate the total by subtracting credit from debit but euhm yours is much better :)